# How to restore the Process Name column in Process Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, process-explorer

Currently, [Process Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer)'s window does not show the process name:

[image: link text]

(When I run Process Explorer as another user, the column displays correctly.)

I have tried dragging all the column handlers, but the process name column still will not appear. Right clicking the column bar brings the *Select Columns* dialog, where the *Process Name* checkbox is checked and disabled.

How can I fix that? I figure the easiest way would be to simply clear the settings from my registry, but I can't find the relevant key.

Comment: Removed by bad answer, give me a few and I'll answer the right question :)

Comment: @JNK, no problem, we're all human.

Comment: How did you manage to hide it?

Comment: @Michael, the registry key which held that column's width got deleted. Hardly something you can do with the GUI :)

Comment: exactly, that is what's so confusing :P did you really edit this yourself in the register and then ask it here or did procexpl just wake up one day and say "hey, I think you can cope without the processname, I'll fix it for ya'" :) Just wondering if you made some special action when it disappeared I guess, it is a strange bug/feature

Comment: @Default, Happened to me and tons of others. Some sort of strange bug.

Comment: To me this happened when the system run out of Windows USER objects (happened while reproducing and debugging a resource leak issue)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using regedit, remove the key `HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer`, then start Process Explorer.

I would suggest to first Export the key, just in case.

Comment: A quick comparing shows the problem was with me was lacking the `0` value in the ` HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer\Process Columns\ ` key, for some reason. I can now just add the missing value it in the backed up and get my old config back.

Comment: +1 Harry!  I was driving.  Badp, sorry for the bum answer earlier.

Comment: Adding `0` didn't work. Deleting the key worked.

Comment: If this happens regularly, you can use **View » Save Column Set** to save the state, and when the process name column vanishes again, use **View » Load Column Set** to restore the layout.

Answer (score 5):

The following did the trick for me:

- Close Process Explorer. Make sure that it does not stay open in the tray.
- Add a `REG_DWORD` named `0` and with a value greater than 0 (column width) to `HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer\ProcessColumns`
- Modify `HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer\ProcessImageColumnWidth`, setting it to a value greater than 0.
- Increment `HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer\PrcessColumnCount` by one.

Comment: slight typo: PrcessColumnCount -> ProcessColumnCount

Comment: @MarkT fixed...

Comment: Actually the typo is in the app - the correct spelling is PrcessColumnCount.

Comment: @G-Wiz is correct so I have undone CJBS's fix

Answer (score -1):

Further to Andz answer ...

I did the following:

- Close Process Explorer. Make sure that it does not stay open in the tray.
- Add a new key of type: REG_DWORD with a value: 136
  (column width) to:
  HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer\ProcessColumns
- Modify key:
  HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer\ProcessImageColumnWidth
  and setting it to a value: 136
- Increment key:
  HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Process Explorer\ProcessColumnCount
  by one.   Mine was 8 so I set mine to: 9
  It stayed here after.